# R summing up total for each class for each id

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Say I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
      classname = c("Welding", "Welding", "Auto", "HVAC", "Plumbing"),
      hours = c(3, 2, 4, 1, 2))
```

I.e.,

```
   id  classname  hours
1   1   Welding     3
2   1   Welding     2
3   1   Auto        4
4   2   HVAC        1
5   2   Plumbing    2
```

I'm trying to figure out how to summarize the data in a way that gives me, for each id, a list of the classes they took as well as how many hours of each class. I would want these to be in a list so I can keep it one row per id. So, I would want it to return:

```
   id     class.list     class.hours
1   1    Welding, Auto       5,4   
2   2    HVAC, Plumbing      1,2
```

I was able to figure out how to get it to return the class.list.

```
library(dplyr)
classes <- df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarise(class.list = list(unique(as.character(classname))))
```

This gives me:

```
   id     class.list     
1   1    Welding, Auto         
2   2    HVAC, Plumbing
```

But I'm not sure how I could get it to sum the number of hours for each of those classes (class.hours).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, this can be accomplished with two calls to `aggregate`. The inner call sums the hours and the outer call "concatenates" the hours and the class names. In the outer call of `aggregate`, `cbind` is used to include both the hours and the class names in the output, and also to provide the desired variable names.

```
# convert class name to character variable
df$classname <- as.character(df$classname)
# aggregate
aggregate(cbind("class.hours"=hours, "class.list"=classname)~id,
          data=aggregate(hours~id+classname, data=df, FUN=sum), toString)
  id class.hours     class.list
1  1        4, 5  Auto, Welding
2  2        1, 2 HVAC, Plumbing
```

In `data.table`, roughly the same output is produced with a chained statement.

```
setDT(df)[, .(hours=sum(hours)), by=.(id, classname)][, lapply(.SD, toString), by=id]
   id      classname hours
1:  1  Welding, Auto  5, 4
2:  2 HVAC, Plumbing  1, 2
```

The variable names could then be set using the `data.table` `setnames` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it using dplyr:

```
classes <- df %>%
  group_by(id, classname) %>%
  summarise(hours = sum(hours)) %>%
  summarise(class.list = list(unique(as.character(classname))),
            class.hours = list(hours))
```

The first summarise peels of the latest group by (classname). It is not necessary to use unique() anymore, but I kept it in there to match the part you already had.